# Python Programing - Os Module - Replace

Tags: python

### What I Want

I have written a code that opens a file (currentcode) gets it's text finds it in another file (text.txt) and replaces currentcode with a new int.

### My Code

```
import os
currentcode = open('currentcode.txt','r+')
code = currentcode.read()
print('Choose File: ')
print('1: File One > ')
file = input('Enter Number Of File: ')
file = 'C:/text.txt'
old_text = code
new_text = str(int(code) + 1)
print('Opened File')
f1 = open(file, 'r')
f2 = open(file, 'w')
f2.write(replace(old_text, new_text))
currentcode.write(new_text)
f1.close()
f2.close()
```

### Output After Running

When I Run This Code I Get:

```
Choose File: 
1: File One > 
Enter Number Of File: 1
Opened File
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DanielandZoe\Desktop\scripys\Replace.py", line 18, in     <module>
    f2.write(replace(old_text, new_text))
NameError: name 'replace' is not defined
```

Comment: What do you expect `replace(old_text, new_text)` to do... did you just mean `f2.write(new_text)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NameError: name 'replace' is not defined
```

That means python couldn't find a module, class or function called 'replace'.

If you want to replace text on a file, you need to get its contents as a string, not as a file-like object (like you're doing now), then you replace the contents using the `replace` method on your `string` and finally, write the contents to the desired file.

Answer (score 0):

`string.replace()` is a method for strings:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace

what is in f2? Not a string. You should read the lines of the file.